# ScreenPointtoRay Creating problems for mouse follow script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am confused as to why my game cursor follow script does not seem to perform differently based on the character's position. I want the player to press "E" if the player hovers the mouse over the character's hand and clicks and drags the arm will move up and down following the mouse position.

The script was working until I moved my character along the X axis and found that the location the mouse had to click and drag stayed at the arm's original position even as the 
 character, his arm, and camera moved away. Would anyone have any idea why? I've pasted in the script for finding the Mouse's position and the script for having my game object copy the mouse's position.

I uploaded some videos of the script working on YouTube as well
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grhnqckOfc0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZlLLgnU8yMc

Thanks for your time!

```
public static class GameCursor
```

{

```
 public static LayerMask mask;


 public static Vector2 WorldPosition
 {
     get
     {
         float distance;
         int mask = 1<<9; //setting layer mask to layer 9
         mask = ~mask; //setting the layer mask to ignore layer(~)
             //adding in the layermask to raycast will ignore 9th layer



         var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
         Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 10000f, Color.black);
         if (_gamePlane.Raycast(ray, out distance))
             return ray.GetPoint(distance);
```

return Vector2.zero;

```
     }
 }
 private static Plane _gamePlane = new Plane(Vector3.forward,0);
```

}

```
 public GameObject ArmR;


 public static Vector2 OffsetPoint;

 public Vector2 OffsetVec2;

 void Start ()

 {

 }


 private void Update()
 {

     if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E)) {


         Follow ();
     }

     if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.E)) {


     }

     //print (transform.eulerAngles.z);
     //Offset.transform.position = OffsetVec2;
     OffsetPoint = GameCursor.WorldPosition + OffsetVec2;

     Vector3 clampedRotation = transform.eulerAngles;
     // Clamp the z value
     if (clampedRotation.z > 90.0f) clampedRotation.z = 180.0f - clampedRotation.z;{
         clampedRotation.z = Mathf.Clamp (clampedRotation.z, 0, 90);
         clampedRotation.z = Mathf.Clamp (clampedRotation.z, -90, 180);

     }

     // assign the clamped rotation
     ArmR.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(clampedRotation);


     //if(ArmR.transform.eulerAngles.z >= 350 || transform.eulerAngles.z <= 270){

         //Debug.Log ("no");



     //}

     if(ArmR.transform.eulerAngles.z == 0){

         //Debug.Log ("AT0");

     }

     if(ArmR.transform.eulerAngles.z == 90){

         //Debug.Log ("AT90");




     }


     }
```

void Follow(){

```
     ArmR.transform.up = -GameCursor.WorldPosition + OffsetVec2;
 }

 private void OnDrawGizmos()
 {
     Gizmos.DrawIcon(GameCursor.WorldPosition, "wallll", true);

 }
```

}

Comment: Note that StackOverflow's tagging system is adequate and you don't need to (and shouldn't, as per the tagging help page) place tags in your question title.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry about that!

Comment: Oh, no worries :) It was more of an FYI than a complaint.